# How can I have two sessions in differently sized windows without tmux resizing the pane?

Tags: session, tmux

I'm currently working with several sessions on several terminals on the same tmux instance (but different sessions).

My plan is to have them "share" the instance but not individual windows. That is, the terminals would be on different windows most of the time.

My problem here is that tmux automatically resizes all windows to the smallest terminal in the instance, which would make sense if I were sharing windows but doesn't in this case.

Is there any configuration option or some way to tell tmux to not automatically resize windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to redraw tmux window when switching smaller monitor to bigger one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `set-window-option -g aggressive-resize`?

In fact, I never met this issue. According to my experience, tmux will not resize windows in one session according to the terminal size of another session.