# Tmux grid border in second session window

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I attached to an existing tmux session from a second iterm2 window on a second screen.

`tmux new-session -t matt`

For some reason my session has a dotted border around the window. Why is this happening?

[image: tmux grid border]

Comment: Also... feel a bit stupid now since I just noticed it says in the bottom right hand corner (size 105x30 from a smaller client)... :|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This border appears when the second window's zoom does not match the first windows zoom. Press `cmd +/-` to make the window's zoom match and it will go away.

Comment: Doesn't that just change the font size? (which, I suppose, does resolve this in a sense.)

Answer (score 6):

This is very similar to this question: [Is there any way to redraw tmux window when switching smaller monitor to bigger one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger)

One way to prevent this (the dots around the "useful" portion) is to detach all other sessions when you attach:

`$ tmux attach -d -t matt`

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to detach the other sessions. Enter your tmux prefix (e.g. Ctrl+b) and then enter the following command

```
:resize-window -A
```

I found it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218815/tmux-force-resize-window/570015#570015