# tmux: Why doesn't it scale to full window size, despite there being only 1 session?

Tags: tmux

Running `:ls` shows there only being 1 session:

```
0: 1 windows (created Tue Sep 19 10:16:50 2023) (attached)
```

Yet, the window still doesn't take the full available space, akin to what's shown in a related question:

- [Tmux grid border in second session window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756616/tmux-grid-border-in-second-session-window)

`pgrep tmux` returns 2 PIDs though: is that's because I have 2 panes opened (in that 1 `window` above)?

`:resize-window -A` helps, though I'd like to understand why the scale-down happens with (supposedly) only 1 session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the window to occupy full size in the current terminal:

```
set-option -w -g aggressive-resize on
```