# Moving between two seperate terminal/tmux windows

Tags: vim, terminal, tmux

I'm currently using an extra monitor so I'm running two tmux sessions in two separate terminals (one for each screen). The problem is every time I want to move between screens I have to manually move my cursor and click the other screen before my cursor will move over, this is super annoying. I'm on MacOS 10.12, using v2.7 of Terminal and v2.2 of tmux.

I've currently tried:

- `cmd` + `shift` + arrow keys, but that only works when the tabs are actually stuck together on the same screen
- Using `tmux switch -t []` or `tmux attach -t []` doesn't manually move the cursor over, it just changes the current screens session, syncing the one session onto both screens.
- Just using one session, but there's this annoying quirk where the external monitors dimensions fit to my macbooks smaller screen size. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger?rq=1) it states that tmux "limits the dimensions of a window to the smallest of each dimension across all the sessions to which the window is attached. If it did not do this there would be no sensible way to display the whole window area for all the attached clients." So there's no way to fix that I think.

Is there some easy command to move between the two terminal windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-backquote (<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>) cycles through the open windows in Terminal.