# tmux: how to adjust the tmux session's width to fit in the terminal panel?

Tags: ssh, tmux, iterm2

when I re-attach a tmux session, the width of the tmux window is still the previous width and padded with white dots:

[image: screenshot]

So my question is how to adjust the tmux width to fit in the terminal panel? The ideal setting would be the tmux session's width is auto-adjusted whenever re-attached.

PS: I am using iterm2 on mac.

EDIT: This is actually answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19280187/1464263

Comment: This is actually answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19280187/1464263

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you have another client attached to this session and it's screen width is half your screen width. If you detach that second session those dots should go away.

`tmux ls` will show you all the sessions.

`tmux detach` will allow you to detach the session.

Answer (score 1):

I have not yet figured out how to do this automatically.
But if you use `xterm`,
you can do this manually:

1. detach from the `tmux` session,
2. type `resize` into your terminal and run it,
3. return to your session and the window should be resized.