# TMUX added one more window which I cannot close

Tags: tmux

I am new to TMUX and tried to ask Google correctly but didn't find the answer.
I've been wording on one of the panes which was separated into two windows. One day, I opened the tmux and found out that the third window suddenly appeared.
And I have no idea how to close it. I've tried ctrl+b + right arrow. But the cursor didn't move there. So I assume it's not a regular window

Could you advise, how should I close it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to redraw tmux window when switching smaller monitor to bigger one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger)

Comment: Actually no, this didn't help me. Still have the same screen. I've tried to detach all the users

Comment: @jeremysprofile I found another user who opened the same window on the smaller size screen and physically reached him. So the idea you shared with me is the right one. Thank you!